# Send an email with attachment using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, attachment

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a list of emails. I want to build a routine that send email automatically to those email addresses. I also want to attach a PDF to this email. The PDF file is located in my Google Drive.

When running the following script, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getAs in object FileIterator. (line
>   21, file "Code")

I'm new to Google Spreadsheets, please can you help me out?

This is the code:

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test123.pdf')
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The method [`DriveApp.getFilesByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)) returns a [file iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), not an individual file. This is why you can't just grab the contents of `file`. A more correct version is

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test123.pdf');
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
  }
```

If there is no file with given name, no email is sent. If there is more than one file with the given name (which can easily happen in Google Drive), you'll send whatever is the first file that comes up in the iterator.

If you want a more reliable way of grabbing files, use [DriveApp.getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))

Answer (score 2):

In your code you wrote:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test123.pdf')
```

`file` is now an object containing all files with the name 'test123.pdf'
The file in the object you want is `file[0]`

In order to get the file you want, you can use

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
     attachments: [file[0].getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     })
```

Comment: This is incorrect; file is an instance of [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next()) which is not an array. `file[0]` would be undefined. Use `file.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `MailApp` code sample, on the [Google Developers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) website, I noticed the following difference:
[image]

I suggest that you add the **blob**.

Reference: [SendMail with advanced options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29)

Comment: This code sample has "blob" because it is sending __two__ attachments; one from a file, and one from a blob created on the fly. This isn't related to the issue the OP had.

Comment: In the future, don't post screenshots as they aren't searchable, copyable, or accessible (eg they don't work for screen readers used by the blind)