# "getAs()" error - send an email with attachment using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, attachment

I am very new to Google Apps Script and struggling. Here is my problem: Trying to send multiple emails via spreadsheet. Want to attach a PDF to those mails. Getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getAs" of undefined.

This is the code (primarily taken from [Send an email with attachment using Google Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/send-an-email-with-attachment-using-google-apps-script)):

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2);  
var subject = range.getValues();   
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9);  
var numRows = range.getValues();   
var startRow = 4;                  
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows,9 ) 
var data = dataRange.getValues();  
for (i in data) {
 var row = data[i];
  var emailAddress = row[0];      
  var message = row[8];           
 var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('PPT A4.pdf');
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
 name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
 attachments: [file[0].getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
});
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are copying code from a wrong answer, that's what... Generally, you'll get more competent help with Google Apps Script on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`DriveApp.getFilesByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)) returns a [file iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), not an array. This is why `file[0]` is undefined. Use `file.next()` (after checking that   `file.hasNext()` is true; if it's false then there is no file with that name).